# The Proxied handler for `filename` could not be loaded

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am getting a runtime error

org.eclipse.cpre.runtime - org.eclipse.ui - 0 - The Proxied handler for `filename` could not be loaded

It seems like it can not find the handler class file.  But the code in the handler file executes.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was calling a class that was not in the right directory location.